# Function call stack: train_function error when train with LSTM

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I get `Function call stack: train_function error` whenever I try to train with `LSTM`

Here is a sample of what my data looks like:

```
Unnamed: 0       STDEV1      AVG1  ...       AVG2        MDN2     EMOSI
0            0  0.289292  0.207629  ...   8.807916   11.992098      1
1            1  0.250791  0.413052  ...  69.249512  101.720074      1
2            2  0.253807  0.338387  ...  31.580711   19.017516      1
3            3  0.263384  0.407921  ...  32.818473   26.808509      1
4            4  0.226528  0.455874  ...  73.241437   75.999870      1
5            5  0.277033  0.221476  ...   8.942901    8.350342      1
6            6  0.292980  0.410113  ...  28.749170   26.776201      1
7            7  0.285785  0.420846  ...  11.603344   11.883280      1
.....................................................................
35          35  0.239678  0.118683  ...   0.711407    0.659205      4
36          36  0.264014  0.573877  ...   1.295760    1.617357      4
37          37  0.188601  0.521860  ...  86.919618   83.608340      4
38          38  0.313663  0.278360  ...   0.966535    0.940959      4
39          39  0.309995  0.354291  ...   0.381528    0.291138      4
```

This is how the data preprocessing is done:

```py
X = np.array(df.drop('EMOSI',axis=1))
y = np.array(pd.get_dummies(df['EMOSI']))
length = 40
num_train = 29
index = np.random.randint(0,length, size=length)
train_X = X[index[0:num_train]]
train_Y = y[index[0:num_train]]
test_X = X[index[num_train:]]
test_Y = y[index[num_train:]]
```

and this is my model

```py
def create_model():
    model = keras.models.Sequential([
        keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=5, output_dim=7),
        keras.layers.LSTM(7),
        keras.layers.Dense(4,activation='softmax')
        ])
    optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.01)
    model.compile(
        loss='categorical_crossentropy',
        optimizer=optimizer,
        metrics=['acc']
    )
    model.summary()
    return model
```

When I train the data:

```py
history = model.fit(
     train_X,
     train_Y,
     epochs=200,
     validation_data=(test_X,test_Y),
     callbacks=[early_stopping],
     verbose=0
     )

>>> Errors may have originated from an input operation.
    Input Source operations connected to node sequential/embedding/embedding_lookup:
    sequential/embedding/embedding_lookup/1883 (defined at C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\contextlib.py:81)

    Function call stack:
    train_function
```

Here is the summary of my model:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding (Embedding)        (None, None, 7)           35        
_________________________________________________________________
lstm (LSTM)                  (None, 7)                 420       
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 4)                 32        
=================================================================
Total params: 487
Trainable params: 487
Non-trainable params: 0
```

So my guess is that my data has only `2 dimensions`, while the first layer of my model expects `3 dimensions`. But that could be wrong because the `3rd dimension` can be input from the `LSTM` layer output.
I have no idea on how to solve this.

*edit, here is the full part of the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Kuliah\Tugas Akhir\Source Code\test_git\SkripsiEmosiRNN\main.py", line 91, in <module>
    callbacks=[early_stopping],
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1100, in fit
    tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 828, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 888, in _call
    return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 2943, in __call__
    filtered_flat_args, captured_inputs=graph_function.captured_inputs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1919, in _call_flat
    ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 560, in call
    ctx=ctx)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 60, in quick_execute
    inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  indices[0,0] = 8 is not in [0, 5)
     [[node sequential/embedding/embedding_lookup (defined at E:\Kuliah\Tugas Akhir\Source Code\test_git\SkripsiEmosiRNN\main.py:91) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_3063]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node sequential/embedding/embedding_lookup:
 sequential/embedding/embedding_lookup/1885 (defined at C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\contextlib.py:81)

Function call stack:
train_function
```

Comment: Not sure on how to resolve this but is Keras updated to latest version?

Comment: You included only part of the error, please include the full traceback.

Comment: @AdityaK yes its the latest version of Keras

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy updated the full traceback at the post, thank you

Comment: Do you know how Embedding layers work? Because you are not using it correctly, the vocabulary size seems to be incorrect.